# Place with well-treated elephants on Bali or Lombok, Indonesia?

Tags: indonesia, nature-and-wildlife, bali, lombok, zoos

I'm planning a trip to Indonesia: Lombok and Bali, and I'd love to see elephants there.

It's clear that most of the elephant parks are about as *ethical* as animal circuses and constantly abuse the elephants for the tourists' pleasure. I googled a bit and even zoos and places that call themselves 'shelters' and 'rescues' offer elephant rides and elephant shows. And I want no part of that.

Do you know of any places that treat animals well on Bali or Lombok where one can see elephants and maybe participate in bathing and/or feeding them? Or is looking for such a place a fool’s errand as they’re all pretty much in the same business?

I would also appreciate any input on how to find places like this regardless of location (maybe you had found one in other SEA country). Maybe you have some general guidelines on that?

---

Or is this subject much more complex and am I wrong to immediately disqualify an animal park from my search because they offer elephants rides and elephant shows? Please share your insight.

Comment: FYI this page about ethical and unethical [wildlife tourism](https://clairesfootsteps.com/bali-animals/) in Bali.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the link! Claire has a pretty insightful website.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there aren't any responsible and ethical elephant parks or any animal parks for that matter in Bali or Lombok. Even the coffee plantations sometimes have caged Luwaks for show that is quite a sore eye to see. I think the only ok-ish place is the **Turtle Centre for Conservation and Education** in Serangan - https://tcecserangan.jimdo.com/

Comment: Yep, that's what I expected =(. Thanks for the input!